# what is the word or expression?

Tags: expressions

You didn't think highly of something and after you hear good things about it and can you say ("It looks different now")?
Is the expression correct? If it isn't, how would you say when you want to say something like the expression in the bracket.

Comment: Are you asking about how to say that you are revising your original negative opinion of something after having heard someone else praise that thing?

Answer (score 1):

You could say *"Now I see things in a different perspective".*

Answer (score -1):

Not really, "It looks different now." might imply something physically looking different.

A more suitable response might be "I've changed my mind.", meaning you have thought about it and now your opinion is different. [Marriam-Webster's definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/change%20one%27s%20mind):

> to change one's decision or opinion about something

If it is stronger of more emotional, you could use "I've had a change of heart." [Marriam-Webster's definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/change%20of%20heart):

> a reversal in position or attitude

Such as in

> I was going to destroy everything on earth, but then I *had a change of heart*, and started gardening.

Comment: "It looks different now" doesn't at all imply anything physically looking different.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin - On the contrary, that is the only thing that sentence implies.